# Why doesn't my WordPress,LearnPress plugin, page show lessons?

Tags: wordpress, web

I want to create a e-learn platform with WordPress. I installed LearnPress plugin and I added several *Courses* and *Lessons* among the courses. I added dummy content for each lesson. However when I want to view a Lesson (doesn't matter which one) the page is freezed in a loading loop, like in the snapshot below:
[image: Course 1 selected, Lesson 1 selected]

In the console I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>
> ```
> at p (main.min.js:94)
> at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.min.js:182)
> at i (jquery.js:2)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
> at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
> at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)
> ```

The error is pointing to an undefined element but why is giving me this error since I didn't modify the code inside the plugin. I followed other forum questions related to this issue but couldn't find any ansewer. What am I missing? Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: I suggest you contact the plugin authors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe LearnPress conflict with activated theme on your site, or other plugins. Try switch activated theme to default theme of WordPress. and disable other plugin.